# What does $B$ have to equal in order for a proper distribution?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, expected-value

Given the joint pdf: $$g(x,y) = \begin{Bmatrix}
Bxy &\text{if  } x+y \leq 1 \\ 
 0& \text{o.w.} 
\end{Bmatrix}$$

I want to know the value of $B$ for $g(x,y)$ to be a proper pdf.

My attempt: We need to have $g(x,y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} Bxy = 1$ for a proper pdf.

So $$g(x,y) = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} Bxy = 1$$

From here, I can solve for $B$, which equals $4$.

Is my solution correct? While I am sure about the range of values for $x$, I am not sure about the range of $y$.

**Edit:** From the hint below, I found $B=24$ for $g$ to be a proper pdf. 
 However, I am not sure how to find the expectations $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$. Any help with that would be appreciated.

I am using these formulas and ranges $E(X) = \int_{0}^{1}x g(x,y) dx$ $E(Y) = \int_{0}^{1}y g(x,y) dy$ to find both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you would want to restrict $x$ and $y$ to positive values. Otherwise $g$ is not integrable so there is no value of $B$ to make it a density function.

Your answer is not correct even after this modification . You need $\int _0^{1}\int_0^{1-y} Bxydxdy=1$. This gives $\int_0^{1} By(1-y)^{2}/2dy=1$. I will let you finish.

$EX=\int _0^{1}\int_0^{1-y} Bx^{2}ydxdy$ and $EY=\int _0^{1}\int_0^{1-y} Bxy^{2}dxdy$.

Comment: I see. I get $B=24$ after solving it. Is that correct? Also how would I find the expectations of $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$? I have made an edit.

Comment: @OGC Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Thanks. could you help with finding $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$. I just need some help with ranges in each. I can compute it after that. I am using these formulas and ranges $E(X) = \int_{0}^{1}x g(x,y) dx$ $E(Y) = \int_{0}^{1}y g(x,y) dy$ to find both

Comment: @OGC Answer edited.

Comment: Thank you. Is it the same formula for E(Y) as well?

Comment: @OGC Typo in my answer corrected.